# Returning resource from PHP function

Tags: php, mysql, function

I am trying to create a function that returns a PHP resource like so:

```
function getCategoryCount(){
    $qry = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM category") or die(mysql_error());
    return $qry;
}
```

When I call this function it doesn't seem to return me a resource like I expected. Any thoughts?

EDIT >
Running `var_dump(getCategoryCount());` give me resource(4)

```
            $qry = getCategoryCount();

            echo '<ul>';

            while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($qry)){

                echo '<li><a href="index.php#">'.$row["name"].' ('.getProductsWithCategory($row["id"]).')</a></li>';

            }

            echo '</ul>';
```

Comment: What does `var_dump(getCategoryCount());` tell you?

Comment: What *does* it return? How are you trying out?

Comment: Have you try it with mysql_fetch_array or mysql_fetch_assoc?

Comment: @halfdan if I run var_dump = resource(4)

Comment: Don't get it.... You want a resource, it give you a resource. Whats the problem again?

Comment: The code works as it should, but I don't think it does what you expect it to. What are you trying to do?

Comment: OK so the problem I am having now is different to the original. When I return the resource I assign it to a variable and then try and use it in the loop. But the first element in the DB is missing. Any Ideas

Comment: -1 for the posting the code which seems so far away from the actual one.

Comment: What does the output of your edit give you?

Answer (score 2):

> But the first element in the DB is missing. Any Ideas

Sure. You are retreiving it somewhere else. Most likely right after executing the query or before runnibg the while loop